# Mobile responsive menu – sub menu not working

Tags: html, css, menu

I have developed this site: http://bellamedica.co.uk/dev/

The problem I have is the **sub-menu** (for treatments) doesn't seem to work on the **mobile site**. When I try to click on treatments to open the sub-menu it goes on the page instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

I am not asking for the code but just some help on what to do.

Thank You.

Comment: which browser are you using? It seems working fine in Chrome. However, I can see the sub-menu after hovering Treatment.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: I am using chrome, and the problem is that there should be three sub menu's when you click on the little arrow, but it isn't showing.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant on the mobile site. So if your resize it to fit the mobile menu, it doesn't show the sub menu's.

Comment: you can use <span> elements that you do not want to go to a different page or href ="javascript :;" but you can use javascripit:; some browsers may not support it

Comment: @AadilMangera On this site, try instead to provide code and expect code (as part of an explanation) to be given back to you. This question does not have very much that anyone else can learn from, which is part of the point on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this jquery to for working in mobile, Using this you can check if li has ul then change attribute of a 'href'

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 992){ if ($('.show-menu li').children("ul").length) {
        $('.show-menu li').children("ul").siblings('a').attr('href', 'javascript::void()');
    } 
    }
});
```

or

```
if($('.top-nav > ul').hasClass('show-menu')){
            if ($(window).width() < 992) {
                if ($('.show-menu li').children("ul").length) {
                    $('.show-menu li').children("ul").siblings('a').attr('href', 'javascript::void()');
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant. The only problem is that when you click on treatments, it loads the sub-menus but only waits for like one second and then changes page.

Comment: Is it like that on your browser, or is it only me?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, i tried it on this link : http://bellamedica.co.uk/dev/test.html (created a test page)

Comment: Add it on page load or when menu is opened

Comment: Im really sorry, but i don't seem to understand. I added the jquery on the <head> section with a CNN from Google

Comment: Thank you so much. It still doesn't seem to work on my browser (maybe its cached). Can you please check on your browser to see if it's working. Thank You.

Comment: Thank you so much. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you can use javascript to prevent redirect to another page